# Updating the locale using the Client object model

Tags: client-object-model

I'd like to set the the Site Settings -->locale setting to English (United Kingdom) using the client object model. Is this possible? This setting can be found browsing the SP site
**Site Settings** --> **Site Administration**: **Regional Settings**--> **Locale** dropdown List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible however you can create a service which can get and set website's locale for you using server side code.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405136/sharepoint-client-object-model-locale)

Comment: Thank you ---too much work involved just to change this setting. Thanks for the reference too